# is it allowed to get user device id

Tags: ios

is that allowed to get user device id, I'm using following code to fetch id but my build still showing in process from last an hour now.

```
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

please your advice will matter

regards,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: just asking is there any other better way to get ?

Comment: No you're asking about Apple policy.

Comment: no if code is available then this should be allowed...

Comment: Your build showing "Processing" in iTunes Connect has absolutely nothing to do with your code.

Comment: When you think about it, using code that you are not allowed to use would case your app to be rejected, not to be "processing".

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for the call. It is absolutely clear what it does and what it doesn't. There is nothing in the documentation that says you are not supposed to use it. Think about it, if you were not supposed to use it, why would the call be there in the first place?

The rest of your question "but my build still showing in process from last an hour now", I honestly have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Consider that I'm not looking over your shoulder while you are typing, and it is difficult reading your mind over a long distance. So please write clearly what this sentence is supposed to mean.